# Subdivide surface based on intersection

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, vertices, edges

I have a question. The situation is as follows:
[image: situation]

So there is a sphere and a prism going straight through the sphere.

Now I would like to:

1. Add vertices and edges to the sphere mesh along the line of
   intersection
2. Select all the surface-faces within the region of
   intersection to work with them e.g. apply a specific material

I feel like there has to be a way to do it without scripting, but I really don't know how...

Thanks for any help in advance:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I recalled another option called Knife Project.

In Edit mode of the cube remove the top face like this:

[image]

In Object mode select cube first and sphere second.

[image]

Then go to edit mode. Select all. Make top orthographic view and use Knife project operation from Mesh menu.

[image]

Check Cut trough box

[image]

Now you can delete your cube and when you go to edit mode with your sphere you can see faces were intersected. So you can select them separately and assign another material.

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: For me it worked even without top face delete. I think if you check box "Cut trough" no need to delete top face. And in this case it'll make intersection in the bottom of the sphere as well

Answer (score 0):

I think Boolean modifier could help.

Comment: Thanks for contributing an answer! Please consider expanding on it so that it is more useful for the OP and for future visitors. Thanks :)

Comment: @LiliaLilia Consider merging both answers